# Extract JSON with multi-dimension array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an ajax request that returns an array (data) :

```
{"errors":{"first_name":1,"last_name":1,"email":1},"error":1}
```

I used :

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

I can check the error value using **obj['error']** but now, I need to loop the **errors** array to add/remove an error class on each appropriate field. I don't know how to extract it and create the loop (with $.each, for instance). I have to mention I'm not supposed to know each key name, that's what I need to get.

Comment: Note that you have an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $.each() to iterate over that object,

```
$.each(obj.errors,function(k,v){
  console.log(k,v); //Here k and v are keys and values
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajaprabhu Aravindasam !